# How to compare two deploy commits of Heroku?

Tags: git, heroku

I would like to how what are all the files changed between two commits of Heroku?

ex: testapp$ heroku releases

```
v953  Deploy bce8f28                            heroku@test.org  2015/10/02 14:08:50
v952  Deploy faaed90                            heroku@test.org  2015/10/02 09:59:26
```

How can I compare the changes between these two deploys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to do this via Git.  It's as simple as `git diff faaed90 bce8f28`.

Comment: I tried it, But it shows the below error
`git diff  faaed90  bce8f28
fatal: ambiguous argument 'bce8f28': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

Comment: That seems...fishy.  Are you sure your local repository is in sync with your remote repository?

Comment: Ah sorry after doing git pull heroku it worked.. thanks! :-)